# Como acessar o resultado do Python-Shell fora do escopo da função

Tags: javascript, python, funções, classes

Olá! Estou fazendo uma api usando o Python no back-end quanto ao script do python está tudo ok! Eu vou receber uma frase no Javascript e através do python-shell vou processa-la no python, até aí está as mil maravilhas e está tudo dando certo, conforme segue o código abaixo:

```
const {PythonShell} = require('python-shell');

var options = {
    mode: 'text',
    args: ['não gostei do pão']
};

PythonShell.run('my_script.py', options, function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    
    console.log(result)
});
```

Onde no var options eu passo o argumento que é a frase que o backend vai processar, nesse caso "não gostei do pão". O problema todo está na segunda parte do código

```
PythonShell.run('my_script.py', options, function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    
    console.log(result)
});
```

O resultado aparece no terminal, mas eu não consigo acessar ela fora do escopo do Python-shell.run(), o que eu gostaria de saber é como salvar o result numa variável que eu possa usar fora do escopo. O que eu já tentei foi o seguinte:

```
const {PythonShell} = require('python-shell');
var resultado

var options = {
    mode: 'text',
    args: ['não gostei do pão']
};

PythonShell.run('my_script.py', options, function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    
    resultado = result
    //console.log(result)
});

console.log(resultado)
```

A saída no console é *undefined* da mesma forma se usar o "let" e o const da error dizendo que falta método de inicialização, já dando o console.log(resultado) dentro do escopo do PythonShell.run() dá tudo ok! Só fora não funciona kkkkk imagino que deva ser algo bem básico, mas não manjo quase nada de JS

Desde já grato pelas dicas!

Comment: Algo me diz que é por assincrono, apesar de não conhecer esse package. Podes testar fazendo `setTimeout(() => console.log(resultado), 1000)`, e ver se já dá.

Comment: @Miguel O resultado já aparece normalmente no console.log() dentro do PythonShell, o problema é que eu não consigo atribuir ele a nenhuma variável

Comment: Eu digo para fazeres fora, onde tens `console.log(resultado)`, só para testar a ver se a minha teoria se verifica

Comment: @Miguel que bruxaria foi essa kkkkkk! Apareceu no console a análise da frase, agora o que faço? Já perdi a linha de raciocíno kkkkk

Comment: tens de garantir que o que queres fazer  com isso só acontece depois (dentro desse escopro), ex chamas uma função com a execução seguinte